# Is there any css for remove the view tabs text underlined in Eclipse RCP4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

In my part class I removed @Focus annotation method which implemented

```
@Focus
public void setFocus() {
    viewer.getControl().setFocus();
}
```

after that tab text underline not visible. But when open window with single part tab text underline is visible, if I click anywhere on window underline gone.
How to remove tab text underline?

Answer (score 0):

The underline is drawn if the `CTabFolder` used for the part has focus. So you should **always** define an `@Focus` method for the part and set the focus to some other control in the part.

The actual drawing of the tab is done by the tab renderer which you can set in the CSS using `swt-tab-renderer`:

```css
CTabFolder
{
  swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
}
```

However tab renderers are rather complex and difficult to write.

The actual code in the standard renderer for the underline is:

```java
if (parent.isFocusControl()) {
    Display display = parent.getDisplay();
    if (parent.simple || parent.single) {
        gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        gc.drawFocus(xDraw-1, textY-1, extent.x+2, extent.y+2);
    } else {
        gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(BUTTON_BORDER));
        gc.drawLine(xDraw, textY+extent.y+1, xDraw+extent.x+1, textY+extent.y+1);
    }
}
```

`parent` in this code is the `CTabFolder` (from `org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolderRenderer`)